# How can I make the box for contenteditable text disappear?

Tags: css, contenteditable

I am using contenteditable on my web pages. This works fine but the browser puts an ugly border around the editable section when it is activated. Also, some of these borders are not erased when the focus is changed to another element on the page.

Safari creates a light blue border, Firefox uses a thin black line, so there is some browser interpretation at work here.

I have tried explicitly setting the border on the editable sections to none and making that CSS property important, but this does not change the browser's behavior.

My question:

Is there a way to influence the styling of the page element that overrules the border property when the user has clicked inside it to start editing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this style  ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8svwn0c/)):

```
[contenteditable="true"]:active, [contenteditable="true"]:focus
{
   border:none;
   outline:none;
}
```

To let all *contenteditable* elements not use border and outline when focuesed.

EDIT: I found an excellent [tutorial](http://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2012/01/23/html5-contenteditable-and-css/)

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I did not know about the 'outline' property. Now I do.

Comment: @4everJang you are wellcome, feel free to accept the answer if solved your problem :)

Comment: I wrote that "excellent tutorial". Upvoted it just because... I appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding outline:none in css for the form elements to remove the border highlight property outline:none in css for input elements.

For example:

```
    input:focus{
      outline:none;
    }

    textarea:focus{
      outline:none;
    }

    select:focus{
      outline:none;
    }
```

For working code find the [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/anoojb28/jq1s8c9z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
[contenteditable="true"]:active,
[contenteditable="true"]:focus
{
border:none !important;
outline:none !important;
}
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide reference in your code for why this is a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.